# Angular2 & RxJS - caching a service that takes a parameter

Tags: angular, caching, rxjs

I'm trying to add caching to an Angular2 HTTP service and just can't seem to figure it out.

I followed other posts and have it working perfectly for HTTP services that don't take any parameters e.g.

```js
workSummaries = this.http.get('http://locahost:8080/teams')
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .publishReplay(1, 3000)
            .refCount()
            .take(1);
```

However I'm lost in trying to figure out can I make above work when I introduce a teamId parameter that should be sent with the request.

So ideally if the same teamId has been used in the last X seconds just read from the cache else if it's a new teamId or 3 seconds has past then call the service.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Kevin.

Comment: use a `Map<number,Observable<Team>>`

Comment: Hadn't thought of that but that seems like a good idea. Would you be kind enough to be able to hack together a few lines to roughly show what this would look like? I'm coming from a Java background so my JS isn't the best!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a Map to maintain the teamID/team association (I didn't touch the Observable creation part):

```js
summaries = new Map < number, Observable < Team >> ();

getTeam(id: number) {
  if (!this.summaries.get(id)) {
    let team = this.http.get('http://locahost:8080/teams/' + id)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .publishReplay(1, 3000)
      .refCount()
      .take(1);
    this.summaries.set(id, team)
  }
  return this.summaries.get(id);
}
```